# Simple Script Appears to Run Forever With No Output...?

Tags: csv, powershell

I've created a simple PowerShell script in order to change the header value of one column in a group of CSV files. When I initiate the script as a `.ps1` file on a test folder containing 25 CSV files, the script appears to run (blinking cursor appears), but it's been running for over an hour now and no output files have appeared as of yet.

Could anyone point out what could be going wrong here? I have written and executed several PowerShell scripts on this computer successfully in the past, but have never come across this issue and searching has yielded no results.

```
#Rename the first Column header in each output file to 'VZA' so you can work
#with the data

#Iterate code through 211 possible files
$i = 1
While ($i -le 211) {
  #Set the variable to the filename with the iteration number
  $filename = "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\20dSum550Output$i.csv"

  #Check to see if that a file with $filename exists. If not, skip to the next
  #iteration of $i. If so, run the code change the column header
  If (Test-Path $filename) {
    #Import the CSV and change the column header to VZA
    Import-CSV $filename |
      Select-Object @{ expression={_."550 1587600 VZA"}; label='VZA' } |
      Export-Csv -NoType "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\fixed20dSum550Output$i.csv"
  }
}
```

EDIT:
It appears I had missed the `$i++` term and the code now runs properly, however, the output consists solely of the `VZA` header and none of the data from the imported CSV file. Where am I going wrong, I am assuming somewhere in the `Select-Object` code?

Comment: Where in the script are you modifying `$i`?  I see it set initially and then never changed, which means it'll always be less than 211, and the loop will never stop.

Comment: Aha, I definitely missed the $i++ I should have included in between the final two curly brackets. Problem solved. Thank you sir!

Comment: Now that the code is running, another problem has cropped up in the results - the output contains nothing but the 'VZA' header and none of the data from within the input CSV file. Any idea where I am going wrong, or should I ask this question in a new thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the script you pasted, the variable `$i` is never changed inside the loop.  In each iteration, it has its initial value of 1, which is always less than 211, and the `while` statement will never exit.

To be clear, the `while` statement does not modify the loop variable itself.  To count from 1 to 211, you need to increment the variable inside the loop, so that it will eventually reach the end.

```
$i = 1
while($i -le 211) {
  write-output "Running iteration $i"
  # loop stuff here

  # Increment the counter
  $i += 1
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the Powershell version of a `for` loop

```
1..211 | foreach {
  write-output "Running iteration $_"
  # loop stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that. However, I've run into a problem in the code itself, which I've added to the OP as an edit... Should I ask that question in a new thread? I am sorta new around here.

Comment: That should probably go into a new question, to get the attention it deserves.